# ProbeError: unrecognized file format. Node js getting Error on (.svg .gif) files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the dimensions and size of images from the URL.
I am using npm package **probe-image-size**  but it gives me Error **ProbeError: unrecognized file format** on .svg  and .gif files such as https://www.se.com//us/shop-static/assets/images/brand/squared-logo-green.svg
https://soneparseaapacidprodstg.blob.core.windows.net/datatoyoustaging/brandLogo.gif

```
const probe = require("probe-image-size");
const getFileMetaData = (fileUrl) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    probe(fileUrl)
      .then((metaData) => resolve(metaData))
      .catch((err) => reject(err));
  });
```

Comment: Show the code you're using and the problematic files.

Comment: const probe = require('probe-image-size');
const getFileMetaData = (fileUrl) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    probe(fileUrl).then((metaData) => resolve(metaData)).catch((err) => reject(err));
})

Comment: this is file url.https://www.se.com//us/shop-static/assets/images/brand/squared-logo-green.svg

Comment: Both files work fine for me, doing just `await probe("...")` with `probe-image-size` version 7.2.1 on Node 16.13.

Comment: yes, it's working fine when I give a single file URL. I have a list of multiple media file URLs and I am using the map() method to iterate over an array and sometimes it gives me an Error unrecognized file format.

Comment: Well, why didn't you tell us that 4 hours ago, or show _that_ code?